# How to speed up A*x if A is not a dense matrix with non-zeros entries being +1 or -1?

Tags: matlab

In the question, A is a square matrix and x is a vector. The non-zero entries of A can only be 1 or -1. Then how to speed up A*x in Matlab?

I asked this question, because A*x contains multiplication operations that are computation-expensive.

However, if A only contains some +1 and -1, and assume y is a row vector from A, then y*x can avoid multiplication operations. You just need group the entries of x into 2, one is corresponding to the entries +1 of y, and the other one is corresponding to the entries -1 of y. Then do a summation of these 2 groups respectively, and do a subtraction.

Comment: If you know how algorithm should look like, you may easily implement it and [profile it yourself](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html). I bet `A*x` would work just fine - don't be suprised if "grouping" entries would actually take more time than simple multiplication. Outperforming LAPACK is not an easy task.

Comment: MATLAB matrix multiplication is really fast, I doubt you'll be able to beat it. Also, `*` should be parallelized so maybe make sure your MATLAB instance has access to multiple threads. Lastly are you sure you need to speed it up? This sounds like premature optimization since you haven't given any indication of why you think it's going to be too slow for you.

Comment: If A is sparse, you can extract the positions of +1 and -1 using find. Then use ACCUMARRAY to perform the summation that you suggested. I've been using this trick before but depending on the size and sparsity of A the highly optimized matrix multiplication may be faster.

Comment: Don't delete your questions and then re-ask them because you are not satisfied with the information provided.

Comment: @Dan Hi, I saw your codes yesterday, but today they are gone...Can I have them again?

Comment: @olivia my answer was incorrect. I thought the values of `x` were either `1` or `-1` but since that applies to `A` and not `x` my answer won't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed this up in MATLAB is to take advantage of the sparse structure of `A` (rather than the +1, -1 structure). You can realize huge speedups this way if `A` is sparse enough:

```
N = 1e4;
k = .0001;

% setup
x = rand(N, 1);

inds = find(rand(1,N^2) <= k);
values = 2*(randi(2, 1, length(inds))-1)-1;

% dense
fprintf('dense\n')
A = zeros(N,N);
A(inds) = values;

for i = 1:5
    tic;
    y = A*x;
    toc;
end

% sparse
fprintf('sparse\n')
A = sparse(N,N);
A(inds) = values;

for i = 1:5
    tic;
    y = A*x;
    toc;
end
```